# Are there standard names for the patterns of batch/queue failure handling?

Tags: design-patterns

Assume I have a batch/queue/collection of items that require individual processing. Some different ways to handle errors when processing items in a batch include:

1. Fail batch on first error, no state is changed.
2. Fail batch on first error, update state only on already processed items.
3. Record error and resume processing, update state on all successfully processed items.

Are there standard names I could use to communicate these ideas more concisely in discussion and code?

Answer (score 1):

Failing on first error is called `fail-fast`

Hiding error and doing as much as possible is called `fail-safe`

Answer (score 1):

There is a very similar thing in PowerShell to define the behavior if an error occurs when the script is executed. The behavior is controlled by the global variable `$ErrorActionPreference`.

There are the following values which can be set:

- Stop: Displays the error message and stops executing.
- Inquire: Displays the error message and asks you whether you want to continue.
- Continue: Displays the error message and continues executing.
- Suspend: Automatically suspends a workflow job to allow for further investigation. After investigation, the workflow can be resumed.
- SilentlyContinue: No effect. The error message is not displayed and execution continues without interruption.

Taken from https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847796.aspx